# Sending out emails based on date in Google Sheets Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Script that will send an email for every cell that contains today's date. Here's what I have so far:

```
function email() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var rowCounter = 1;
     var limit = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Fetch the estimated dates & Today's date
  var estimatedReturnDateRange = sheet.getRange("F:F"); 
    var estimatedReturnDate = estimatedReturnDateRange.getCell(rowCounter, 1);
  var todayDateRange = sheet.getRange("S1"); 
  var todayDate = todayDateRange.getValue();


  // Check totals sales
  for(i=1; i<=limit; i++){

  if (estimatedReturnDate = todayDate){
      // Fetch the email address
      var emailAddress = "maxbkimmel@gmail.com";

      // Send Alert Email.
      var message = estimatedReturnDate; // Second column
      var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);


  }
  rowCounter++;
  estimatedReturnDate = estimatedReturnDateRange.getCell(rowCounter, 1);

  }  
  rowCounter =1;
}
```

This is how I envision the logic of the script working:

estimatedReturnDate initially grabs the first cell in column F, which is a list of dates.

todayDate grabs cell S1, which contains today's date.

a for loop then loops through all rows of the sheet, and checks if estimatedReturnDate = todayDate.
If it does, an email is sent that contains the Row Number that matched today's date.

Then, rowCounter is incremented, estimatedReturnDate is set to the next cell in the row, and the loop runs again.

The problem I'm having is that when I run this script, an email is sent out for each row in the sheet, regardless of whether estimatedReturnDate matches todayDate or not.

Does anyone know what would be causing this?

Comment: estimatedReturnDate = todayDate should be estimatedReturnDate == todayDate, I think

Answer (score 2):

```
function email() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheets()[0];//This is always the left most sheet but not necessarily the same sheet depending how users move the sheets around.
  var vA=sheet.getRange(1,5,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues()
  var dt=new Date();
  var toda=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight yesterday
  var tmro=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()+1).valueOf();//midnight today
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var dt=new Date(vA[i][0]).valueOf();//date from column5 of spreadsheet
    //dt is between midnight yesterday and midnight today
    if(dt>=toda && dt<=tmro){
      var emailAddress = "maxbkimmel@gmail.com";
      var message = Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy");
      var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }  
}
```

[Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

[Date Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: why is `vA[i][0]` set to `[0]` for the entire for loop, can you explain this?

Comment: where is `vA[i][0]` set to 0.

Comment: sorry i mean can you explain the syntax? what does the second square bracket indicate and why is it set to 0?

Comment: Because the range is only one column but even a one column range is still a two dimensional object.  It looks like [[],[],[],...]. It's the first column of the ith row.